# PowerShell pipe and xpath query

Tags: powershell, xpath, pipe

I have a little problem using the pipe. Here is what I have done:

```
[xml]$y= (gc alpha.xml)
[xml]$p_v = (gc beta.xml)
$b=$x.report.row[1].ELEMENT_ID
$y.SelectNodes("//report/row[elementRootID/text()='$b']").pID|
    %{
        if ($p_v.SelectNodes("//report/row[id/text()='$_']").obpdID = $NULL)
            {write "Hurra!"}}
```

, where alpha.xml looks like

```
<report>
<row>
<pID>418</pID>
<elementRootID>63789</elementRootID>
</row>
</report>
```

and beta.xml loks like:

```
<report>
<row>
<ID>418</ID>
<obpdID>248</obpdID>
</row>
</report>
```

When I am doing it that way powershell is not finding the property obpdID in the row-tag. If I am typing it directly, then it is working. It would be great, if someone can give me a hint what is going wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does `$x` get its value?

Comment: $x is also a xml document, similar to alpha and beta.

Comment: [Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because you're using `=` where you should be using `-eq` i.e.

```
if ($p_v.SelectNodes("//report/row[id/text()='$_']").obpdID = $NULL)
```

should be

```
if ($p_v.SelectNodes("//report/row[id/text()='$_']").obpdID -eq $NULL)
```

---

But for a more complete answer/a better way [IMO] of doing things you should adopt the following method.

Because.... XPath is icky... PowerShell is ace!

```
[xml]$alpha = @"
<report>
    <row>
        <pID>418</pID>
        <elementRootID>63789</elementRootID>
    </row>
</report>
"@

[xml]$beta = @"
<report>
    <row>
        <ID>418</ID>
        <obpdID>248</obpdID>
    </row>
    <row>
        <ID>419</ID>
        <obpdID>249</obpdID>
    </row>
</report> 
"@

# Because our object is of [xml] type, we can just naigate the DOM directly without XPath!
$alpha_pID           = $alpha.report.row.pID
$alpha_elementRootID = $alpha.report.row.elementRootID

# And because it's an object; we can use all our lovely PS CmdLets instead, too!
$beta_obpdID = ($beta.report.row | Where-Object ID -EQ $alpha_pID).obpdID

# Results
$alpha_pID
$beta_obpdID
```

---

Bonus for @OP

Given an initial ElementRootID (`$b` in your code; `$elementRootID` in mine) - find the matching records in `$alpha` and *then* find the resultant, related matches in `$beta` and return them as a single object.

```
[xml]$alpha = @"
<report>
    <row>
        <pID>418</pID>
        <elementRootID>63789</elementRootID>
    </row>
    <row>
        <pID>419</pID>
        <elementRootID>63789</elementRootID>
    </row>
</report>
"@

[xml]$beta = @"
<report>
    <row>
        <ID>418</ID>
        <obpdID>248</obpdID>
    </row>
    <row>
        <ID>419</ID>
        <obpdID>249</obpdID>
    </row>
</report> 
"@

$elementRootID = 63789

$results = $alpha.report.row |
    Where-Object elementRootID -EQ $elementRootID |
    ForEach-Object {
        $beta.report.row |
            Where-Object ID -EQ $_.pID |
            Select-Object -Property @{Name="elementRootID"; Expression={$elementRootID}}, @{Name="pID"; Expression={$_.ID}}, obpdID
    }

$results
```

Results

```
elementRootID pID obpdID
------------- --- ------
        63789 418 248   
        63789 419 249
```

Comment: This is a solution. Thanks for that. Any clue why the other way isn't working?

Comment: @ DanielSommerfeld answer updated to include this detail. Also; you  should adopt the non-XPath method.

Comment: @gvee In that method, you need to parse through each object if it doesn't have a unique identifier (such as some kind of ID).  I'm not sure on the speed of `Where-Object` versus `SelectNodes()`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The speed of the non-xpath-method is much slower than the other.

Comment: @DanielSommerfeld I think you need to fully explain what you are actually trying to achieve. We've spotted the mistake in your code, but can't offer much more assistance without further explanation.

Comment: @gvee Thanks for all the comments. We have solved the problem I had. I now had to find pID from alpha as ID in beta and return obpdID. Then looking for obpdID as ID in beta. So finding recursively the root. (For better understanding: beta is a hierarchy but not as a tree but solved with id and parentID as a property. Maybe it is smarter to create a file including a real tree and use the power of powershell instead of the recurse search.

Comment: @DanielSommerfeld check my latest edit. Has a little extra added based on your previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Adoption of the non-xpath solution:

```
($y.report.row | Where-Object elementRootID -EQ $b).pID |
%{
    if (($p_v.report.row | Where-Object id -eq $_).obpdID -eq $NULL)
    {$PG_ID = $_}
    else{$PG_ID = ($p_v.report.row | Where-Object id -eq $_).obpdID}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

XPath is case-sensitive. This ought to work:

```
if ($p_v.SelectNodes("//report/row[ID/text()='$_']").obpdID -eq $NULL)
```

But as gvee says, it's much easier using built-in xml functionality in powershell.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix the problem.